# Problem on Discrete Random Variable

Tags: distributions, self-study, density-function, discrete-data

Please kindly give a pointer to this question. Generating the discrete variables seems unlikely!

Entrance to a country can be denied for a number of reasons. When someone arrives by air, and their entry is denied, they get put into a detention hotel before deportation. While in the hotel they can appeal against the deportation decision. If the appeal is accepted they will be allowed to enter the country, if it’s rejected, they have one more chance for appeal before getting deported. If their second appeal is successful, they can leave the hotel and enter the country, but if this second appeal is unsuccessful again, they will be deported. The possible scenarios can be found in the table below.

[image]

Historic data shows that 70% of people who end up in the detention hotel, are there because they made a minor mistake in the visa application, while 10% get put into the detention hotel because they lied in the visa application (and it’s possible to prove it), while 20% have missing documents.

If a minor mistake was the reason behind the initial rejection, then each appeal has a 95% chance of being successful. However, if the reason was a provable lie or missing documents, then an appeal gets rejected with probability 0.93.

**Question:** Assume that in January 20 people were taken to the detention hotel. Let X denote the number of court appeals these 20 people will make before they are either let into the country or deported.
(i) What are the possible values of X?

Here is my approach:

Given the above, the number of appeals X is between 20≤X≤40. Since there can only be maximum of 40 appeals if the first 20 failed.

However, listing each number of outcome (value for X) with its mass function using this direct approach is probably not tenable? I can't see whether the binomial distribution supports this approach either?

Comment: You may get more help if you edit your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: The above raised concerns have been effected.